# Python tkinter text not align in in pack

Tags: python, tkinter

[image]

text not properly align in pack. I want the text to be on top and pack on bottom but every time I try to align the "Enter Password Length" disappear

```
from tkinter import Button, Entry , Label, Tk
from tkinter.constants import END
import pyperclip
import string




password_chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation

class gui:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("Password Generator")
        self.window.geometry("300x300")
        # Label Frame
        label_title = Label(text="Password Generator", fg="#800000",font=("Inter", 15, "bold"))
        label_title.pack(pady=15)
        self.label = Label(
        self.window, text="Enter Password Length",font=("Inter"))
        self.label.pack(pady=20,)
        # Entry box for number of characters
        self.length_entry_box = Entry(self.label, width=24,)
        self.length_entry_box.pack(padx=10, pady=15)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gui().window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you use `self.label` as the parent of `self.length_entry_box`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm just a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you give the master option in the entry as `self.label` this should be `self.window`.

`master=self.label`(or the first parameter) means entry should inside `self.label`.

```py
from tkinter import Button, Entry, Label, Tk
from tkinter.constants import END
import pyperclip
import string




password_chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation

class gui:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("Password Generator")
        self.window.geometry("300x300")
        # Label Frame
        label_title = Label(text="Password Generator", fg="#800000",font=("Inter", 15, "bold"))
        label_title.pack(pady=15)
        self.label = Label(
        self.window, text="Enter Password Length",font=("Inter"))
        self.label.pack(pady=20,)
        # Entry box for number of characters
        self.length_entry_box = Entry(self.window, width=24,) # self.label changes to self.window.
        self.length_entry_box.pack(padx=10, pady=15)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gui().window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

In line 23. Removed object `self.label,`

```
from tkinter import Button, Entry , Label, Tk
from tkinter.constants import END
import pyperclip
import string


password_chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation

class gui:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("Password Generator")
        self.window.geometry("300x300")
        # Label Frame
        label_title = Label(text="Password Generator", fg="#800000",font=("Inter", 15, "bold"))
        label_title.pack(pady=15)
        self.label = Label(
        self.window, text="Enter Password Length",font=("Inter"))
        self.label.pack(pady=20,)
        # Entry box for number of characters
        self.length_entry_box = Entry(width=24)
        self.length_entry_box.pack(padx=10, pady=15)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gui().window.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]